# Intent filter for launcher and send activity

Tags: android, filter, android-intent

I'm trying to get my main activity to be the launcher activity and also receive send events. Somehow I can't seem to make both work same time. Either I have the launcher icon in the app tray but then not in image share menu in from gallery for example. How can I make both work at the same time.

With this intent filter the icon is in app tray but not in share menu.

```
         <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        </intent-filter>
```

With this one I have it in the share but not in app tray

```
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I suspect it has something to do with the data element and I tried this but it didn't work

```
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
               <data android:mimeType="image/*">
            </action>  
        </intent-filter>
```

Any help much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyCompatTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            </intent-filter>

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the solution. You can actually have more than one intent-filter tag in an action. So the right code was

```
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thank you - was having exactly the same problems. Makes sense.

Comment: How do you customize menu item display name in share menu? I know it's possible (see Read It Later app)

Comment: @aloneguid You can change the label for that activity. This also works for getting a different icon. ex. `<activity android:name="MyActivity" android:label="Show In Share Menu" android:icon="@drawable/share_icon" />`

Comment: this doesnt seem to work anymore? I think your intent-filter with SEND also needs a DEFAULT category