# Game not visible in the menu after .apk installation

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I am facing a issue where my game becomes invisible in the menu after installation. Also when .apk installed, OPEN button becomes disabled and i'm unable to launch my game.

I made this game in Unity3D. I want to do deep-linking in my game so created my own Activity named as MainActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity and also did some changes in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;

public class MainActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d("MainActivity", "onCreate called!");
    }

    @Override 
    public void startActivity(Intent intent) 
    { 
        boolean isStartActivity = true;

        Uri uri = intent.getData(); 

        if (uri != null && uri.getScheme().equals("abc")) 
        {
            isStartActivity = false;
        }

        if (isStartActivity) 
        { 
            super.startActivity(intent); 
        } 
        else 
        {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "MainActivity.startActivity() : uri = " + uri.toString());    
            UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Main Menu", "JuliusReward", uri.toString());
        } 
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.abc.xyz">

    <supports-screens
      android:smallScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true"/>

    <!-- android:debuggable should be removed in release build -->
    <application
      android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:debuggable="true">

      <activity android:name="com.abc.xyz.MainActivity">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

              <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "myapp://com.example.myapp” -->
              <data android:scheme="abc" android:host="com.example.abc"/>
          </intent-filter>
    </activity>

      <activity android:name="org.onepf.openiab.UnityProxyActivity"
              android:launchMode="singleTask"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
              android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
      </activity>

      <receiver android:name="com.amazon.device.iap.ResponseReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.NOTIFY"
                android:permission="com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.Permission.NOTIFY" />
        </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
    </application>

    <!--all-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <!--Google Play-->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <!--For Tablets-->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this post [Intent filter for launcher and send activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265909/intent-filter-for-launcher-and-send-activity)

You should have an

`<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>`

and 
`<intent-filter>
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>`

Comment: Where should i keep <data android:scheme="swingaliens" android:host="com.example.swingaliens"/>

Comment: in the second one this: <intent-filter>
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>