# App icon does not display in applications (on home screen)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

My app used to work just fine, its icon displayed when installed in applications and it was uploaded to the Play Store. Now when I install it, it is like invisible, and in the Play Store it just says Uninstall, not open. What would be the reason for this?

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="redacted" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    >
    <activity
        android:name=".aboutclass"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="redacted.aboutclass" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="redacted.MainActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: check your email registered with Google Play, they may of updated you

Comment: Nothing. Any other suggestions?

Comment: post link to google play page

Comment: Updated the link with the manifest, can you find anything in this?

Comment: have you tried different marketplaces (.co.uk / .com) same result?

Comment: Yes, I have the same result even when downloaded from my computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem occurs when you include the `<data>` element in the same intent-filter as your action.MAIN, which does not expect any data.
You could try splitting the intent-filter like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="redacted.MainActivity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http"/>
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

See [this previous answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265909/intent-filter-for-launcher-and-send-activity)